# Using Azure Storage Emulator with Azure SDK 2.6 on Tables

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-storage-emulator, azure-emulator

Has anyone successfully used Azure Storage Emulator 4.0 in conjunction with Azure SDK 2.6 for .NET when trying to emulate tables storage? I'm just trying to step through the Table Quickstarts but it looks like something doesn't recognise that the emulator is running. However all works fine with the Queues quickstart. It looks like a versions incompatibility? Here's what the quickstart displays when trying the do `CloudTable table = CreateTableAsync().Result;` :

> Azure Storage Table Sample
>
> 1. Create a Table for the demo If you are running with the default configuration please make sure you have started the storage emulator.
>      Press the Windows key and type Azure Storage to select and run it from
>      the list of applications - then restart the sample.

Comment: I'm using SDK 2.6/Storage Emulator 4.0 successfully for tables, queues and blobs. Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @GauravMantri Nope, no error message beyond what was displayed above (at the command prompt). Couldn't see anything even when stepping through with the debugger. Did you swap out the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configure and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage references to those in the 2.6 SDK?

Comment: Could it be related to port conflict? Please check if the port used by storage emulator table service is not being used by some other service.

Comment: @GauravMantri I think I figured it out, it wasn't a port thing but thanks for the suggestion. It was todo with a reference version mismatch between the packages listed in the package.config and the ones referenced in the project references. Once I'd swapped out the references in the project with the ones listed in the package.config then all was well :) Thanks anyhow :)